# Microservicios - Manejo de Operaciones

Tags: c#, microservices

Quería saber si alguno conoce algún libro, blog, o tutorial para leer teoría de como manejar operaciones complejas con **microservicios**.

Me explico un poco mejor: Tengo una operación compleja, que ejecuta varios métodos de diferentes microservicios. Si uno de las ejecuciones de estos microservicios falla, como se manejaría el "rollback" de estas operaciones?
Hay alguna teoría al respecto donde podría empezar? Existen algunos patrones a seguir que ayudan en estos casos?

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! como manejar el rollback depende de lo que te permitan hacer los servicios que estas llamando. La primer parte de tu pregunta es un no no (no esta bien visto pedir enlances a documentacion). La segunda, tal vez con mas contexto, se puede contestar.

Comment: No son muy recomendables las [transacciones](https://www.baeldung.com/transactions-across-microservices), para el uso de microservicios, de eso se trata que cada microservicio tenga independencia, pero deberias especificar mas tu caso, por ejemplo la venta de un producto, si el pago es rechazado no deshaces todo el proceso de la compra, simplemente se actualiza el estatus de la orden.

Comment: ¿Te parece si aceptas alguna de las respuestas que te han ofrecido? Es para colaborar con la buena salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 0):

Cuando varios `microservicios` colaboran entre si uno puede fallar es por eso que en caso de `rollback` se debe implementar `servicio de compensacion`

[Compensating Transaction pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction)

Basicamente consiste en invocar un servicio y si alguno falla invocas el servicio previo con la funcionalidad de compensacion que revierte la operacion que se realizo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, umagino microservicios de stock y ventas. Si descuentas el stock de un producto para registrar una venta, si esta ultima falla debes invocar la implementacion de compensacion que vuelve sumar al stock lo que habias quitado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta,

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente en arquitecturas de microservicios mas complejas, se usa el **Saga Pattern**, un patrón que propone el uso de operaciones compensatorias, esto depende del enfoque que se siga, si por orquestación o por coreografía. Recién he publicado un libro en español en el que abordamos 25 patrones de microservicios y como manejar la transaccionalidad, que es donde está exactamente el problema que planteas, es sin dudas el mayor reto de la arquitectura microservicios. Puedes mirar [acá](https://sacavix.com/patrones-para-la-implementacion-de-una-arquitectura-basada-en-microservicios/) en este blog en español hablamos mucho de microservicios https://sacavix.com/